# Mac OSX - Core Animation - how to animate something which is following my cursor?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

So far I have only seen Core Animation has code that looks like this, where the parameters of where to animate to are set in the beginning.

```
- (void) startTopLeftImageViewAnimation{
/* Start from top left corner */ 
[self.xcodeImageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[self.xcodeImageView1 setAlpha:1.0f];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"xcodeImageView1Animation" context:(__bridge void *)self.xcodeImageView1];
/* 3 seconds animation */
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
/* Receive animation delegates */ [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(imageViewDidStop:finished:context:)];
/* End at the bottom right corner */ [self.xcodeImageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(220.0f,
350.0f, 100.0f,
[self.xcodeImageView1 setAlpha:0.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

However, I would like to make an animation in which the graphic follows my mouse cursor. This means that the animation is constantly receiving my mouse-pointer x-y values.

Is there a better alternative to doing "manual" animation like this, and calling drawRect whenever I shift the position of my mouse? Can I use Core Animation for this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code here.
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFill( rect );

    [self drawCircleAtPoint:_circlePt];
}

- (void) drawCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint) point {

    NSBezierPath* thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    NSRect nrect = NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 50, 50);
    [thePath appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect:nrect];
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [thePath stroke];
}
```

Thanks for any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need the point where the mouse cursor is pointing to. The method you have to implement for this is

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

`NSEvent` has a method called

```
- (NSPoint)locationInWindow
```

which gives you, as you might guessed, the position of the cursor in the window.

Now you have to find the location within your view. This is done by `NSView` method

```
- (NSPoint)convertPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint fromView:(NSView *)aView
```

where the point comes from `locationInWindow` and the view is the view in which you want to perform the animation

e.g.

```
CGPoint mousePoint = [[[self window] contentView] convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:self];
```

Then you can either set the position via the views frame or you can use the position property of the views layer.

Comment: Hi my question is more of asking of an efficient way to do animation, it might not have been clear.. apologies for the misunderstanding. Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Changes in Layer properties are animated by default: See  [CA Documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514). But animating a view under the mousepointer can feel laggy (animation time vs. mouse speed). So default animation time set to 0.0f would make the "animation" look right, but …